# How do i make this string a JSON object?

Tags: c#, json

How can I turn the string fetched from the URL to a usable object? I've seen several `Newtonsoft.Json` examples, but none of them work with the layout of the object in the URL.

The code below is what I have so far. (the `DeserializeObject` part currently in the code doesn't work) due to the layout of the object.

**JSON Data:**

```
{
    "totals": {
        "confirmed": 4011,
        "dead": 23,
        "recovered": 7,
        "changes": {
            "newToday": 239,
            "newYesterday": 378,
            "diff": -139,
            "deathsToday": 4,
            "deathsYesterday": 5
        }
    },
    "cases": [
        {
            "confirmed": 989,
            "dead": 4,
            "recovered": 1,
            "name": "Oslo",
            "countyCode": "03",
            "confirmedPer1kCapita": 1.426111833700075
        },
        {
            "confirmed": 1138,
            "dead": 7,
            "recovered": 1,
            "name": "Viken",
            "countyCode": "30",
            "confirmedPer1kCapita": 0.9168805114549636
        },
        {
            "confirmed": 284,
            "dead": 2,
            "recovered": 1,
            "name": "Innlandet",
            "countyCode": "34",
            "confirmedPer1kCapita": 0.7647050904048359
        },
        {
            "confirmed": 440,
            "dead": 0,
            "recovered": 3,
            "name": "Vestland",
            "countyCode": "46",
            "confirmedPer1kCapita": 0.6912467735271338
        },
        {
            "confirmed": 304,
            "dead": 0,
            "recovered": 0,
            "name": "Rogaland",
            "countyCode": "11",
            "confirmedPer1kCapita": 0.633475865403049
        },
        {
            "confirmed": 285,
            "dead": 0,
            "recovered": 0,
            "name": "Trøndelag",
            "countyCode": "50",
            "confirmedPer1kCapita": 0.608062265575995
        },
        {
            "confirmed": 130,
            "dead": 2,
            "recovered": 0,
            "name": "Troms og Finnmark",
            "countyCode": "54",
            "confirmedPer1kCapita": 0.5342956134330138
        },
        {
            "confirmed": 159,
            "dead": 1,
            "recovered": 0,
            "name": "Agder",
            "countyCode": "42",
            "confirmedPer1kCapita": 0.5175259007066344
        },
        {
            "confirmed": 149,
            "dead": 1,
            "recovered": 0,
            "name": "Vestfold og Telemark",
            "countyCode": "38",
            "confirmedPer1kCapita": 0.3552728209138857
        },
        {
            "confirmed": 91,
            "dead": 0,
            "recovered": 1,
            "name": "Møre og Romsdal",
            "countyCode": "15",
            "confirmedPer1kCapita": 0.34308809446610217
        },
        {
            "confirmed": 42,
            "dead": 0,
            "recovered": 0,
            "name": "Nordland",
            "countyCode": "18",
            "confirmedPer1kCapita": 0.17410408937343255
        }
    ],
    "updated": {
        "ts": "2020-03-28T21:23:18+01:00",
        "by": "Morten Asbjørnsen",
        "version": "5154"
    }
}
```

**Code:**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string Address = "https://redutv-api.vg.no/corona/v1/sheets/norway-table-overview?region=county";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Address);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();


        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = null;

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response.CharacterSet))
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
            else
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));

            string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();

            response.Close();
            readStream.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(data);

            //No clue...
            Statistic statistic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Statistic>(data);   

        }
    }

    public class Statistic
    {   
        //needs modifying.
        public string confirmed.total {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Shy of us getting the data ourselves and seeing what it looks like, no clue. Can you share the raw string (or at least a solid representation of it)?

Comment: @gilliduck just browse to the URL in the code sample and you'll see it

Comment: the link is included in the code snippet. (Declared as Address at the top)

Comment: I'm not going to browse to any random site to get the data, if you need help parsing json into an object, you need to share the json. i.e. bundle together everything needed to solve your question into the question. You're more likely to get an answer.

Comment: @gilliduck chill, it's just an API returning JSON. you can always google it first if you're unsure. Anyway the answer is below.

Comment: The guidelines for asking a question state that `it must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself`. That means including the JSON, not telling us to go fetch it from a URL that may not exist at some point in the future.

Comment: Well for everyones sanity, I have posted the JSON response from postman in the question :). I agree with @IanKemp that the JSON needs to be included for future answers .Otherwise everyone will be clueless when they stumble across this answer and the API has gone down.

Answer (score 2):

Your c# class has to have structure *similar* to json

(**Note**: I'm specifically skipping some details of deserialization for simplicity, but in short the parts of your C# class that don't match your json will be skipped - you will have `default` values)

Here's what you can do

1. Download your json from https://redutv-api.vg.no/corona/v1/sheets/norway-table-overview?region=county
2. Generate a c# class based on that json using some tool, for example http://json2csharp.com/ or https://www.jsonutils.com/
3. Rename the generated `RootObject` into something meaningful - this is your `Statistics` class

Depending on the tooling you will get a slightly different result, something similar to the code below

(**Note**: Some details may differ, like collection types can use array, `List<T>` or `IList<T>` depending on the tooling)

As a bonus, if you're able to use .NET Core 3x, [Try the new System.Text.Json APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/) - this is the recommended approach going forward, not `Newtonsoft.JSON`

```
public class Changes
{
    public int newToday { get; set; }
    public int newYesterday { get; set; }
    public int diff { get; set; }
    public int deathsToday { get; set; }
    public int deathsYesterday { get; set; }
}

public class Totals
{
    public int confirmed { get; set; }
    public int dead { get; set; }
    public int recovered { get; set; }
    public Changes changes { get; set; }
}

public class Case
{
    public int confirmed { get; set; }
    public int dead { get; set; }
    public int recovered { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string countyCode { get; set; }
    public double confirmedPer1kCapita { get; set; }
}

public class Updated
{
    public DateTime ts { get; set; }
    public string by { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Totals totals { get; set; }
    public List<Case> cases { get; set; }
    public Updated updated { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: No need for json2csharp if you're using Visual Studio: Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON As Classes

Answer (score 0):

You need an object structure in C# which matches the structure of the JSON you're downloading.

Sites like [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/#) will auto-generate a structure for you and will work with most JSON you can think of.

For the data presented by that URL when I visited it just now, it suggests this:

```
public class Changes
{
    public int newToday { get; set; }
    public int newYesterday { get; set; }
    public int diff { get; set; }
    public int deathsToday { get; set; }
    public int deathsYesterday { get; set; }
}

public class Totals
{
    public int confirmed { get; set; }
    public int dead { get; set; }
    public int recovered { get; set; }
    public Changes changes { get; set; }
}

public class Case
{
    public int confirmed { get; set; }
    public int dead { get; set; }
    public int recovered { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string countyCode { get; set; }
    public double confirmedPer1kCapita { get; set; }
}

public class Updated
{
    public DateTime ts { get; set; }
    public string by { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Totals totals { get; set; }
    public List<Case> cases { get; set; }
    public Updated updated { get; set; }
}
```

You can then run

```
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data);
```

to deserialise it.

Comment: Funny, we answered at the same time and even added the same json to c# generator :-)

Comment: And I was composing an answer also using json2csharp when I saw both of your answers pop up.  ;)

Comment: No need for json2csharp if you're using Visual Studio: Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON As Classes

Comment: Thank you. Thats a very useful site :)
My stupidity and lack of coding skills knows few bounds, and I still don't get it to print the desired outputs.
Here is a .NET fiddle so you can test: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NFEMjT

Comment: @svemal that's because you can't Deserialise directly to "Totals" - the top-level of the JSON corresponds to  RootObject, so you have to deserialise to that, as per my answer. Then you can read from the Totals property _within_ that. Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/u4Ct7l

Answer (score 0):

```
  /* method arguments:
      stream : Stream class instance
      charSet: Character set (in string), default is current system encoding.
      bufferSize: Buffer size, default 1024 bytes
   */
  static async Task<string> readStreamAsync(Stream stream, string charSet = "", int bufferSize = 1024)
  {
        /* read stream to buffers */

        var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        List<byte> buffers = new List<byte>();

        using (var readStream = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            // read stream into buffer
            var n = await readStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            // loop buffer streaming until no more stream data
            while (n > 0)
            {
                // populate buffer into buffer list
                buffers.AddRange(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, n).Array);

                // read stream into buffer
                n = await readStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
        }

        /* return encoded string */

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(charSet))
        {
            // encode buffers array into default encoded string
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(buffers.ToArray());
        }
        else
        {
            // encode buffers array into encoded string based on any character set
            return Encoding.GetEncoding(charSet).GetString(buffers.ToArray());
        }
  }

  /* usage: */

  string data;

  try
  {
      using (var receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream())
      {
          data = await readStreamAsync(receiveStream, response.CharacterSet);
      }
  }
  finally
  {
      response.Close();
  }

  Console.WriteLine(data);

  Statistic statistic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Statistic>(data);
```